# Lambdas Capturing and Forwarding Functors

Tags: c++, reference, perfect-forwarding

I'm trying to better understand how lambdas capture functors and how it relates to perfect forwarding.

The code I have included is a minimal example. My real code uses variadic templates but this captures most of the errors/confusions I've been having. I get different results on different compilers (Visual Studio 2017 vs gcc 4.9.3 and 7.2.0).

The "troubled" line appears to be the instantiation of has_functor given a function pointer, i.e., making y in main.

I have tried 3 different versions of the code by modifying the lambda argument that initializes toil_and_trouble.

- version 1: capture by reference and forward...

  ```
  [&](double d)->double{
    return calls(std::forward<F>(f),d);  
  }
  ```

  This works on all the compilers I have tested and produces the correct results. But it makes me nervous because when rvalues are passed into the constructor, there could be UB like described here: [return a lambda capturing function parameter reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076087/return-a-lambda-capturing-function-parameter-reference)
- version 2: this seems like a compromise in that we accept by value and then forward appropriately:

  ```
  [=](double d) mutable ->double{
    return calls(std::forward<F>(f),d);  
  }
  ```

  This works fine on VS but not on gcc. I also think that by forwarding f, potentially as an xvalue, the lambda may lose its captured functor, i.e., its value might change through being forwarded on and used to make other functors.

  But the compiler error I see actually only comes about when F is deduced to be double(&)(double,double), but not in the other two cases.
- version 3: I thought maybe the forwarding was the problem somehow so I just didn't forward:

  ```
  [=](double d) mutable ->double{
    return calls(f,d);  
  }
  ```

  This works on VS but not gcc, again.

Can someone please comment on these 3 different versions in terms of where UB could arise and how to properly manage the instantiation with function references and rvalues alike?

Quotes from the C++ standard would be helpful, too.

The code is below:

```
#include<utility>
#include<functional>  
#include<iostream>

// functors

double foo(double, double) { return 0.; }

struct G{
  double operator()(double,double) const{ return 0.; }
};

// helper

template<typename Fun>
double calls(Fun&& f, double d){
  return f(0,d);   
}

class has_functor{
private:
  std::function<double(double)> toil_and_trouble;  
public:
  template<typename F>
  has_functor(F&& f) : /* have tried multiple versions of this */
    toil_and_trouble( [&](double d)->double{
      return calls(std::forward<F>(f),d);  
  } ) {}
};


int main(){
  auto x = has_functor(G{});    
  auto y = has_functor(foo);
  auto z = has_functor([](double,double)->double{return 0.;});    
}
```

Comment: GCC 8.1.0 compiles fine...

Comment: @Aconcagua Thank you for checking that. But may I ask which of the 3 versions do compile for gcc 8.1.0?
Also, I'm still not sure why the compiler errors in version 3 happened in the first place. To my knowledge, most of this is just C++11 so not much should be changing between compilers.

Comment: All three variants compiled. Would be interesting to know how clang reacts, currently not installed on my system, though. Possibly GCC just not complying the standard (more recent version accepting the code is a hint to). Saw that happening few other times now (which still is surprisingly often, considering GCC once being famous for its standard compliance – but recently, clang seems to have conquered this place...).

Comment: @Aconcagua: just found https://wandbox.org/ offers a lot of compiler settings. If the website is to be believed then, yes, Clang also compiles it. I'm disappointed in those older versions of gcc.